# SQL to get the dates between start date is included and end date is excluded

Tags: sql

```
SELECT [order id], 
       pickingdate 
FROM   td_order1 
WHERE  sku = xyz 
GROUP  BY pickingdate, 
          [order id] 
HAVING pickingdate >= Min(pickingdate) 
       AND pickingdate <= Max(pickingdate) 
ORDER  BY pickingdate
```

Is there anything wrong in this query?

Comment: `pickingdate < Max(pickingdate)`, if you want to exclude end date

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the query is that you are using unaggregated columns in the `having`.  My recommendation is to use window functions:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             MIN(pickingdate) OVER (PARTITION BY sku) as min_pd,
             MAX(pickingdate) OVER (PARTITION BY sku) as max_pd
      FROM td_order1 o
      WHERE sku = xyz 
     ) o
WHERE pickingdate > min_pd and pickingdate < max_pd
ORDER BY pickingdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your condition as :

```
pickingdate < Max(pickingdate)
```

to exclude end date